# Generate a Json fil whith C++

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I wrote a code in C++ to generate a `.json` file using the JsonCpp library. My issue is that I'm struggling to maintain the display order as it appears in the sequence of code within the file. Currently, the display order is alphabetical, which doesn't match the desired sequence.
To resolve this and maintain the desired order, I'm wondering if there's a solution within the JsonCpp library or an alternative approach or library I should consider ?!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    // Créer un objet Json::Value pour stocker les données
    Json::Value jsonData;

    // Enregistrement 1
    Json::Value enreg1;
    enreg1["CAT"] = "4";
    enreg1["Long"] = "19";
    enreg1["Day"] = "0";
    enreg1["Time"] = "13:15:37:86";
    enreg1["Fspec"] = "fa12gh";

    Json::Value Item1;
    Item1["AI"] = "1a";
    Item1["CC"] = "23";
    enreg1["Item1"] = Item1;

    // Ajouter Enreg_1 à l'objet JSON principal
    jsonData["Enreg_1"] = enreg1;

    // Ouvrir un fichier pour écrire le JSON
    std::ofstream file("do.json");

    if (file.is_open()) {
        // Utiliser un Writer de JsonCpp pour écrire l'objet JSON dans le fichier
        Json::StreamWriterBuilder builder;
        std::unique_ptr<Json::StreamWriter> jsonWriter(builder.newStreamWriter());

        // Écrire l'objet JSON dans le fichier
        jsonWriter->write(jsonData, &file);

        // Fermer le fichier
        file.close();
        std::cout << "Fichier JSON généré avec succès." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier pour écrire." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I expect this :

```
{
    "Enreg_1" : 
    {
        "CAT" : "4",
        "Long" : "19",
        "Day" : "0",
                "Time" : "13:15:37:86",
        "Fspec" : "fa12gh",
        "Item1" : 
        {
            "AI" : "1a",
            "CC" : "23"
        }
    }
}
```

But I have this instead (alphabetical order):

```
{
    "Enreg_1" : 
    {
        "CAT" : "4",
        "Day" : "0",
        "Fspec" : "fa12gh",
        "Item1" : 
        {
            "AI" : "1a",
            "CC" : "23"
        },
        "Long" : "19",
        "Time" : "13:15:37:86"
    }
}
```

Comment: JSON properties are, by definition, unordered.

Comment: Javascript objects don't have any concept of ordering among members of that object. That is keys, can be in any order.  Hence, JSON has no concept of ordering either.  If you really need alphabetical ordering, use an array.  **But I guess the bigger question is this "why is it important to have alphabetical order?"** The consumer of this json will read your object and create an equivalent object identical to the object used to create the json in the first place regardless of the order.

Comment: My psychic powers suggest JsonCpp uses a `std::unordered_map` to hold the keys of an object.  But if it was converted to use `std::map` instead, you might get your alphabetical ordering for free.  That's just a guess, I haven't looked at the jsoncpp code.

Comment: OP doesn't want alphabetical. JsonCpp is using `std::map`

Comment: @GarrGodfrey - yeah, he's not going to get what he wants.  But what he wants is something he doesn't really need.

Comment: I want to maintain the order, as it's specified in my requirements. The example I provided might not exactly represent the real issue I'm facing, but it demonstrates the same need. I would appreciate respectful and constructive responses, without any condescending tone. Thank you for your understanding. @selbie

Comment: @AbdelazizHAMMOUABDALLAHAZIZ - this is one of those situations where you tell the person making the requirements to ease up and probe *why* they need to receive the fields in an expected order. Is it because they (the receiver) isn't using a standard library, but instead are using a custom parser?  Or perhaps they don't understand json that well and over specified the requirement.  It looks like an answer to shift to another json library has been suggested.

Comment: As a software developer it's not my job to discuss the requirements, I just take the task and do implement it in all its details. but you are right. I may in some cases have to discuss the requirements. thank you @selbie

Comment: It's not you job to discuss the customer requirements wrt to business goals, but it is your job as an engineer to tactfully discuss requirements as it pertains to your efficiency of implementation and adherence to schedule. Easily resolved with a quick message such as, *"hey boss, ordering json fields deterministically is non-standard and whoever consumes this won't be using a parser that cares about ordering either. If we stick to the exact requirements, it would add a couple of days to the schedule. Are we certain we need this explicit ordering?"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the commenters on your question have noted, JsonCPP uses an `std::map` to store its object members. If you switch to nlohmann::json you can override the backing store for objects to preserve insertion order.

There is even a [premade type](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/ordered_json/#template-parameters) for you to use:

```
using ordered_json = nlohmann::ordered_json;
```